# How to use CodeIgniter Form Validation using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

**In my HTML :**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.price" placeholder="Position" required/>
<button type="submit" ng-click="validate(data)">Save</button>
```

**In my controllers.js :**

```
$scope.validate = function(data){
    $http.post(
        'http://mysitename.com/folder/controller/method',
    {
        price: data.price
    }
  )
    .success(function(res){
        console.log(res);
    })
    .error(function(res){
        console.log("Error: " + res);
    });
}
```

**In my Controller.php :**

```
public function method() {
    if($postdata = file_get_contents("php://input")) {
      $this->form_validation->set_rules(??????, 'Price', 'required|is_money|trim');
      if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
      {
            echo json_encode(validation_errors());
      } else {
            echo json_encode("working");
      }
    }
}
```

What should I put in my `$this->form_validation->set_rules(??????, ' Price', 'required|is_money|trim');` ?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to validate it before or after the button is pushed?

Comment: Yah, after the button was pushed @ManuelObregozo